# Delete entries in Android MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, android-edittext, multiautocompletetextview

On a MultiAutoCompleteTextView in android I am able to add entries and parse them just fine. After auto completing the most recent item, when I press backspace it will delete all the characters before I autocompleted the item. Great. Now my problem is when I have multiple entries already autocompleted. I want to be able to delete each entry with a single backspace rather than deleting each character individually. I have tried using a TextWatcher but couldn't really get that to go anywhere. Is there a way I could tokenize each entry as its own entity rather than appending it to a string (like google hangouts and facebook do. Note: this isn't a requirement, just a thought of how i could do it). Thanks for any help! I'll post here if I find out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this library

https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete

Allows to use any view as the token and allows a token to be added and deleted as one entity.